# How to add nuget packages to c# project files with nuget.core

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to upgrade a bunch of old c# projects to consume nuget packages that I have made from old assembly dependencies.  I want to write a C# program to update all the csproj files to reference the package.

I have the  code using nuget.core making a dictionary of dependent assemblies to a nuget package.  I can iterate over the references in my project file and find the needed nuget package from my repository.

```
var localRepo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(nugetCachePath);
var packages = localRepo.GetPackages();
foreach (var package in packages)
{
   foreach (var assemblyReference in package.AssemblyReferences)
   {
        assemblyToPackage.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assemblyReference.Name).ToLower(),package);
   }               
}
```

I think I need to use Nuget.Core ProjectManager to add the reference to my project file (csproj).

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Incluse="KB.MyOldAssemblyPackage">
       <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

What I can't figure out is how to get an instance of ProjectManager or any examples on how to use it to add the nuget reference.  I know I could simply inject the xml with an xdocument but since I made the effort to use nuget.core I was hoping to find a solution using it.

Any help out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what ways to manage packages you use now, but if it's `packages.config`, then I think better migrate to `PackageReference`. For it's may use NuGet [PackageReference Upgrader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CloudNimble.NuGetPackageReferenceUpgrader) that convert your dependencies from packages.config to `PackageReference` format.

After that you can [add/remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#feature-availability) our packages with [NuGet Package Manager UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui) extension that built-in in `Visual Studio 2017`.

**UPD2**. `Visual Studio 17 Preview 3` [has](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/04/09/visual-studio-2017-version-15-7-preview-3/) tool for migrate from `packages.config` to `PackageReference`.

---

Also `MSBuild 15.1 +` [has](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets) built-in `NuGet` targets such as [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target) and [pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target) that you can combining with custom build targets. It's make easier build process.

---

If you still want to write program to added references to `.csproj` you can create extension for `Visual Studio`.

---

**UPD1**. Get `IEnumerable<Project>` from [GlobalProjectCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection.globalprojectcollection?view=netframework-4.7.1#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_ProjectCollection_GlobalProjectCollection) and parse libraries names from the Include attributes:

`GetReferences` -

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetReferences(IEnumerable<Project> project)
{
    return project.Select(p => p.GetItems("Reference").Select(i => i.EvaluatedInclude);
}
```

---

After that check availability this library in your `NuGet` repository with help your code and if exists, then remove current reference and create new:

`CreateReference`-

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NuGetReference
{
    public static class Reference
    {
        public static void CreateReference(string projectName, string packageName, string packageVersion)
        {
            Project project = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject(projectName);

            project.AddItemFast("PackageReference", packageName, new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Version", packageVersion) });

            project.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) | [Project Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project?view=netframework-4.7.1) | [GlobalProjectCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection.globalprojectcollection?view=netframework-4.7.1#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_ProjectCollection_GlobalProjectCollection) | [AddItemFast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.additemfast?view=netframework-4.7.1#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_Project_AddItemFast_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_System_String_System_String___)

Comment: I think this is close to what I need to do.  Currently my projects have neither package references nor packages.config. I am trying to create packages or reference existing packages for the assemblies that are currently being copied to output directory before the build.  But there are many so I am trying to find a way to automate the upgrade

Comment: I was trying to experiment with  Migrate packages.config to PackageReference... from a couple of test projects but the option does not show up from either references or packages.config right clicks.  I have Visual Studio 2017  Professional version 15.6.6

Comment: @KenB. Small answer update. UPD. `option does not show up from either references or packages.config right clicks` If we speak about  `PackageReference Upgrader`, then option show when your click on solution or project icon in `Solution Explorer`

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly right.  After I got the code working I saw the old references in solution explorer had yellow triangles and understood that they  needed to be removed as you said.  This code works great for migrating old projects with no packages.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. 
You can't.

The NuGet.Core dll is NuGet 2.x, while PackageReference was introduced in 4.x 
4.x has a more modular approach, and there isn't one package you can use to achieve your goal.

If you have Visual Studio 2017, you can use the latest 15.7 release (to be released in 2 weeks or just use the preview) to migrate your packages to PackageReference. 
That's a built in tool that should handle most of your scenarios if compatible.

If you're really stuck with having to this programmatically the following [code](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.PackageManagement.UI/Actions/PackagesConfigToPackageReferenceMigrator.cs) should be a great start.